# SQL Server 2008 Web edition in a hosting plan?

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Do any hosting companies offer SQL Server 2008 Web edition in a hosting plan.

GoDaddy for instance offers Standard/Enterprise editions which raise the price by $200 or so a month.

I've tried a few hosting companies and can't find the web edition available. Why not?

The web edition is supposed to be only $15/month - but I was hoping to be able to get this pricing through a dedicated server and not have to go off and separately get the licensing. I don't even know if its possible to buy just one copy!?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least one hosting company offers SQL Server 2008 Web edition -- the one I work for.  I have no idea why more don't (I don't have anything to do with administering or setting policy for our Microsoft hosting -- thank $DEITY), but it's on our price list, so it's possible.  I can't imagine that GoDaddy, with their volume-means-everything policies, will talk to you, but I'm sure if you find a more reasonable hosting company and ask them, they'll either be able to special-case it for you, pull out the "products we don't list on the website" price list, or at least explain to you why it's not available from most hosting companies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you rule out the free version of SQL Server Express? DB is limited to 4GB, but for small databases it works great, and you can't beat the price.

Also, if you are looking to buy a dedicated server, ServerIntellect has decent prices and will sell you the web version of sql server for $25/month.

They are a great hosting company - every interaction I have ever had with them is top-notch. I'll be moving back to them soon for my dedicated server.

Comment: Db is NOT limited to 4gb... that limit was raised to 10gb with 2008 R2 express. THat makes it a LOT more ffeasible for pretty much 99% of all websites.

Comment: Another note - ServerIntellect will not SELL you, they will RENT you. Small difference.